# How to back up and restore drupal 8 site?

Tags: drupal-8, migrate

I follow the below steps to back up and restore drupal 7 site.

1) On the source server, upload the backup and migrate module
2) On the source server, take a backup of the database using the back up and migrate module
3) Copy all the site files - Drupal core, modules, themes, and your files folder, and migrate them to the target server in the exact same folder structure as the source server.
4) After that, delete settings.php, and make a copy default.settings.php called settings.php
5) Install Drupal as a new installation on the target server
6) Enable the backup and migrate module on the target server
7) Use the B&M module to import the database backup from step 2

I did follow the same steps to backup and restore in drupal 8 but I am running into issues. Does the backup and restore site in drupal 8 work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

More or less.
Maybe could more simple if you have a backup copy.
If you can create a backup before, using drush, it will be the best way.
So assuming you have a backup copy
From the linux command line, change to the directory where we want to restore our Drupal project. 
 to create the database  in the system:

```
    $ mysqladmin -u [username] -h [host] -p create [database]
```

so the copy of the database will restored from the .sql file that you generated when you backed up:

```
    $ mysql -u [username] -h [host] -p [database]
```

Set the database password.
next go to the rigth directory

```
    cd /folder/site/drupal
```

and unzip the site in the righ place where you need it.

```
    $ tar -xzvf /folder/where/create/backup/filename-backup.tar.gz -C / folder / site / drupal
```